# Hibernate Null checker ignore field on POST request but don't on Put request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, model

I'm using spring boot 2.7. I want to null checker ignore "ID" field on POST request but don't ignore it on PUT request! what's the solution?

Note: I want to do it in one model!

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Data
public class CategoryRequestModel {

    @NotNull
    private String id;   // check on PUT request
                         // not check on POST request

    private String title;
    private String status;
}
```

Comment: Avoid pictures, use code blocks instead.

Answer (score 0):

Mohsen, make sure you're implementing your entity class correctly.
First of all, change your ID variable to the following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

The annotations above ensures the ID variable works like an entity's identification. Now as it represents a unique value, you can make POST requests without passing any value for the id because it's an auto-generated field.

For PUT requests you're gonna always have to specify the id once JPA needs to fetch the object from the DB to make any change.